# Pull files into script from two directories back

Tags: python, path

I have a script that will pull files from two directories back, so the script resides at:

> /folder2/folder1/folder0/script.py

and the files that will be processed will be in folder2.

I can get back one level with "..//" (I'm making a Windows executable with cx_free) but I'm thinking this isn't the best way to do this.

I am setting an input directory and an output directory. I want to keep the paths relative to the location of the script so that "folder2" can be moved without screwing up the functionality of the script or force rewriting of it.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you get the directory where your script is located, like so:

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

And then, if you know you will always use the directory two levels above, just use:

```
target_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, '..', '..')
```

From there you can manipulate files from the target_dir as you please.

**Edit**

From adsmith, instead of joining two ".." paths together, you can instead define target_dir as:

```
target_dir = os.path.sep.join(current_dir.split(os.path.sep)[:-2])
```

Which will simply cut off the last two directories in your path, instead of them ending in a few uglier ".."s.  So, the first method would look something like:

`/path/to/folder2/folder1/directory/../..`

Whereas the second implementation would be:

`/path/to/folder2/`

Comment: It seems silly to use `os.path.join(current_dir,'..','..')`. You're just tacking on two "up" references to a path. Instead do `target_dir = os.path.sep.join(current_dir.split(os.path.sep)[:-2])`

Comment: Good point.  I didn't know that particular method existed before.  I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: The only methods I used there were `str.split` and `str.join`. `os.path.sep` points to the system-specific path separator as a string, so on windows it's `"\\"`. `os.path.sep.join(...)` is just `"\\".join(..)`, and from there we just use string splitting and list slicing to chop off the last two elements.

Comment: Specifically, I didn't know about ```os.path.sep```, which come to think of it is just silly because it HAS to exist.

Comment: I always think it's `os.path.pathsep`, which is actually the system-specific separator for the `PATH` env var. Any time I use it I waste 15-30 minutes debugging that crap.

Answer (score 0):

I would use your suggested method of `os.chdir(r'..\..')` to make sure your current working directory is in `folder2`. I'm not really sure what you're asking though, so maybe clarify why you think this ISN'T the right solution?

Comment: I was setting a directory as `directory = "."` for root, and `directory = "..//"` to go one directory backward. I wasn't using os.chdir, which I will look into. Thanks

Comment: @mattrweaver it's worth noting that IT'S NOT NECESSARY that your current working directory be the same directory as your file (it's common, but not guaranteed). limasxgoesto0's answer IS guaranteed, however. Strongly consider his as an alternative to using a bare `os.chdir(r'..\..')`, although if you're using simple file commands, I don't think you'd have to do much other than `os.chdir(target_dir)` after his two lines of code.